# Wordpress wp-config.php doesn't update with Kubernetes environment variables for the container

Tags: mysql, wordpress, kubernetes, parameters, config

I'm doing a school project for which I want to deploy automatically Wordpress with Kubernetes, linked to an Azure Mysql Server and Database (already exist, created previously with Terraform).

I defined the environment variables in the kubernetes deployment of wordpress, as you can see under:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wordpress
        image: wordpress:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: server-user.mysql.database.azure.com
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
          value: user
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: user-secret
              key: password
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_NAME
          value: user-db
        volumeMounts:
        - name: user-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/html
      volumes:
      - name: user-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pvclaim-user
```

However, when I connect into the pod of wordpress deployment and check wp-config.php, the variables haven't changed :

```
// ** Database settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_NAME', 'wordpress') );

/** Database username */
define( 'DB_USER', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_USER', 'example username') );

/** Database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', getenv_docker('WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD', 'example password') );
```

I tried changing the parameters manually to check if the problem was elsewhere (at the time, I was deploying mysql with kubernetes too): I had a permission issue with the storage of both mysql and wordpress, so I added additional permissions for storageclass:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: storageclass-wordpress
provisioner: file.csi.azure.com
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=999
  - gid=999
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
reclaimPolicy: Delete
allowVolumeExpansion: true
```

The access to mysql seems to be fixed, but the parameters of wordpress still don't update, so I suppose that's not the issue. I'm assuming the docker image comes with the parameters already set up, and kubernetes can't change them? Is there any way to change the parameters automatically?